# App crashes when accessing NSDictionary's values but not when accessing its keys?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdictionary, asihttprequest

I have an NSDictionary object called "myData," and I'm trying to access it from the UITableViewDelegate method "didSelectRowAtIndexPath."

I can perform these operations fine:

```
if(myData == nil) { /* it doesn't print here, so it's not nil */ }
NSLog(@" * Keys: %@", [myData allKeys]); // Outputs all of the keys.
```

But if I try to perform any of THESE operations, the App crashes with no warnings, errors, or output of any kind:

```
[myData objectForKey:@"akey"];
[myData allValues];
```

Anybody have an idea what may be causing this?

Comment: showing us code on how you built the dictionary would be helpful

Comment: It is populated directly from JSON and passed in a Message class' "storage" variable (which is an Array) into my View Controller as a callback from a callback from an ASIHTTPRequest object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like myData was does not contain a valid reference. Do you release it or forgot to retain it after reading?

[Update]: To be on the safe side and exclude this just do one more retain after creating the dictionary (just for testing!) and check whether the crash disappears. If not maybe some other variable is overwriting your myData. Set two breakpoints, one at point where the dictionary is assigned to myData, the other one before the point of crash. Check if you see a reasonable summary e.g. "2 keys pairs".

Comment: To be honest, my memory management skills are not up to par. I was considering that this might be the case, except for two things: 1) why would it still show the keys? Is that because the memory is freed but hasn't been overwritten? And 2) why am I not receiving an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error?

Comment: You are right I would expect an EXC_BAD_ACCESS as well. See my update above.

Comment: I tried retaining it to no avail. I even did myData = [[[msg.storage objectAtIndex:0] copy] retain] and nothing :(.

Comment: Okay another update: if I wait long enough, XCode finally returns an EXC_BAD_ACCESS. However, it takes several minutes for it to do so.

Comment: And one more: I have now done this
NSArray* storageArr = [msg.storage copy];
myData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[storageDict objectAtIndex:0]];
[myData retain];

still nothing...

Comment: me too.. I was accessing the allValues inside a selector passed in to performSelectorWithDelay... it was crashing on objc_msgSend inside CFRetain inside NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects... T-T